# Unable to create a Stored procedure in Redshift Aginity and aginity pro

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, aginity

Trying to create the stored procedure in redshift aginity workbench but it through an error like 'unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
'

In amazon, they already gave the solution for this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html

particular client tool only supported to create the stored procedure.
I want to conform aginity don't have the option to create this?
and
Which is the best tool to create stored-procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE staging.test_sp1(f1 int, f2 varchar)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE INFO 'f1 = %, f2 = %', f1, f2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create RedShift stored procedures in Aginity Pro by using *Run Batch*. Full support will be in the 9/16 release.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be enhanced by the addition of a link or example of Run Batch.

Answer (score 2):

Aginity need to update their tool to pass the dollar quoted procedure body to Redshift correctly. I note that Aginity is able to execute the procedure with `CALL staging.test_sp1()`.

Some other tools have already been updated to allow creation and you can always use `psql` to create the procedure.

Comment: Can you suggest which is the best one for Redshift?

Comment: Aginity will probably have an update that supports this soon. You can also try these other tools: datarow.com , Falcon - plot.ly/free-sql-client-download , sqlectron.github.io , tableplus.com , jetbrains.com/datagrip . Pricing varies, some are free.